# Downloading abstracts using Mendeley

Tags: literature-search, abstract, reference-managers, springer

I am using Mendeley for my reference management. As I am doing a Systematic Literature review, I have to filter out my search result entries based on inclusion and exclusion criteria after reading the abstract. I have exported Springer search results into Mendeley but Springer only allows CSV export of search results and does not include abstracts in it.

I want to ask: is there any way I can download abstracts of articles after importing them into Mendeley?

Comment: Please give the exact name of the database that you are trying to export to (e.g. SpringerLink) because the correct answer depends entirely on the precise database. Even better, include a URL to the database; this helps us help you.

Comment: Its SpringerLink. And ACM Digital Library also. But for now I am concerned with SpringerLink.